# Remove pypy completely from Windows 7

Tags: pypy

I want to uninstall pypy version on window 7 which is compatible to Python 2.7 version. There is no pypy in "Uninstall program" from Control Panel. I have not found any documentation so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPy does not install itself under windows. Removing the directory completely removes the installation.